# Math crossing out

Tags: javascript, math, factorial, largenumber

I am looking to play around with probability that involves a lot if big numbers. To save computing time, I was thinking about having the computer cross out terms like you do in regular math. For example:

> (2*3*7*3) / (3*2*3*3)
>
> Can be simplified to 7/3

If I were to create a Javascript function and pass it two arrays containing multiplication numbers to cross out, how would I go about doing this?

Just to be clear:

If I passed in `[3, 4, 6, 4]` and `[4, 7, 3, 2]`, it would return two arrays: `[4, 6]` and `[7, 2]`

Comment: Do you wish to cancel out the exact matches only ? How about returning [12],[7]  i.e. final simplified form ?

Comment: @SRB Only exact for now. I know how to do the multiplying out and other simplifying stuff so I will just us this with that for my final project

Comment: I've added both, see my answer. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: There were so many good responses it was hard to choose. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not require cancellation beyond exact numbers, this should do:

```
var x = [3, 4, 6, 4];
var y = [4, 7, 3, 2];
for(var i in x)
{
  for(var j in y)
  {
    if(x[i]==y[j])
    {
      x.splice(i,1);
      y.splice(j,1);
    }
  }
}
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

But in case you are interested in further cancellation take this:

```
var x = [3, 4, 6, 4];
var y = [4, 7, 3, 2];
for(var i in x)
{
  for(var j in y)
  {
    if(x[i]%y[j] == 0)
    {
      if(x[i]/y[j] > 1)
      {
        x[i] = x[i]/y[j];
      }
      else{
        x.splice(i,1);
      }
      y.splice(j,1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Wow, I really like the second one, even though it was not what I was after. It brings it into its prime factors! Thanks!

Comment: Well it is not optimized like other answers but will do the job for you.
Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, or:

```
var arr1 = [5,2,3,7,8];
var arr2 = [3,5,2,3];
arr1.sort();
arr2.sort();
var i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
    if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
        ++i;
    } else if (arr1[i] > arr2[j]) {
        ++j;
    } else {
        arr1.splice(i, 1);
        arr2.splice(j, 1);
    }
}
alert(arr1.toString() + "/" + arr2.toString());
```

UPDATE: to display a fraction

```
function prod(arr) {
    var res = 1, i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        res *= arr[i];
    }
    return res;
}

alert(prod(arr1) + "/" + prod(arr2));
```

Comment: Okay, that works. However I would need to add 1 to an array if it is empty so that when multiplying out, it returns 0.

Comment: Do you by any chance know which is more efficient?

Comment: @Bluedog111 I don't get the added 1

Comment: What I am trying to do is simplify a fraction. If, when the program crosses values out, an array is left with none, the answer will not be correct. eg 2/2*3 when crossed out is 1/3 not 0/3. I am just trying to look at what I will need to do to continue.

Comment: @Bluedog111 a sort can be done in O(n*log(n)), that's the complexity of this algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to use a version of inArray (taken from jQuery), then check each element and remove elements as necessary. I'm not sure how well this would perform compared to just doing the calculations though, it would be worth testing on jsPerf.

For example:

```
removeDuplicates([3, 4, 6, 4], [4, 7, 3, 2]);

function removeDuplicates( array_1, array_2 ) {
    array_1.forEach(function(value, index) {
        var in_array = inArray( value, array_2 );
        if ( in_array !== false ) {
            array_1.splice( index, 1 );
            array_2.splice( in_array, 1 );
        }
    });

    console.log(array_1); // [4, 6]
    console.log(array_2); // [7, 2]
}

// from jQuery
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return i;
    }
    return false;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tj6crcdt/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method to do this that has no dependencies. There's a couple of assumptions made that might bite you.

- It tests numbers based on equality. In your use case (probability), this will bite on floating point values.
- It might just be better to run the calculations. For all we know the JavaScript engine of choice is doing better optimizations anyhow.

Here's the code and example usage:

```
var numerator = [2,3,7,3],
denominator = [3,2,3,3],
numerator2 = [3,4,6,4],
denominator2 = [4,7,3,2];

function simplify(num, den) {
  var value = {
    numerator: num.slice(),
    denominator: den.slice()
  },
  done = false,
  remove = function (a, b) {
    for (var aIdx = 0; aIdx < a.length; aIdx++) {
      for (var bIdx = 0; bIdx < b.length; bIdx++) {
        if (a[aIdx] === b[bIdx]) {
          a.splice(aIdx, 1);
          b.splice(bIdx, 1);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    done = true;
  };
  while (!done) {
    remove(value.numerator, value.denominator);
  }
  return value;
}

simplify(numerator, denominator);
simplify(numerator2, denominator2);
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing quite a bit of more research I found a way of doing it.

```
var arr1 = [5,2,3,7,8];
var arr2 = [3,5,2,3];
var extraVals = _.intersection(arr1,arr2);
var arr1Simp = _.difference(arr1, extraVals);
var arr2Simp = _.difference(arr1, extraVals);
```

Or as a function

```
var likeTerms = function(num, down){
    var extraVals = _.intersection(num,down);
    var numSimp = _.difference(num, extraVals);
    var downSimp = _.difference(down, extraVals);

    if(numSimp.length==0){
        numSimp.push(1);
    }
    if(downSimp.length==0){
        downSimp.push(1);
    }
    return {
        num: numSimp,
        down: downSimp
    };
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b4np2b5g/)